# Overwriting edge weight with a formulae

Tags: formula, gephi

I have nodes that have **nodeweight** and edges that have a **edgeweight**. 
I would like to overwrite edgeweight with a formulae edgeweight=(nodeweight * old_edgeweight).

I think there should be some way by using console. 
Is console the only way? What about any excel-like formulas?

Answer (score 0):

You could export your edges as a spreadsheet (data laboratory -> Export spreadsheet), compute this new edgeweight in your favorite spreadsheet editor and then reimport edges again through the data lab.